# Radio buttons with Best In Place form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

I'm wondering if there is any way to have radio buttons update in place using the Best In Place gem.  I'm using it for my form and works great, but Best in place doesn't seem to provide a radio button input type.  I could use check boxes I guess but I'm a bit confused about how to bind a 3 check boxes to the same column.

What I'm looking for is a simple radio button collection bound to a field in my model which looks something like

```
   o  Our Court       #value = true
   o  Their Court     #value = false
   o  Complete         #value = nill
```

When selected I'd like the db to be immediately updated as Best in place does with other changes to input fields.

Any ideas?  Thanks.